# Vuejs2: list of autosize textareas bound to a growing array of objects don't update their value

Tags: javascript, textarea, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I bound https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize to `textarea`s listed in a `v-for`, and I'm seeing a weird data persistence behaviour while growing the array structure bound to that list:

[image: growing textarea in v-for bug animation]

On the left side, inputs are shifted to the bottom as expected, whereas, on the right, freshly bound `textarea`s keep the value of the previous `textarea`!

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/adrienjoly/Lb3yqdso/6/

Any idea of how I could fix this mapping/binding issue?

Comment: `autosizing-textarea` not behaving like a nice boy with vue.

Answer (score 0):

[nachocab gave me this answer](https://github.com/egoist/vue-autosize-textarea/issues/1#issuecomment-285324620):

> Make sure you're using the key attribute. Otherwise, vue will try to re-use existing dom elements, which may lead to the weird behavior you're seeing.

=> it works: https://jsfiddle.net/adrienjoly/Lb3yqdso/8/

```
<p v-for="input, i in inputs">
  <autosizing-textarea :key="input.key" :value="input.text"></autosizing-textarea>
</p>

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: { inputs: [{ key:0 }] },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.inputs.unshift({ key: this.inputs.length });
    },
  },
})
```